# How to preserve imported shapefile's original precision decimals in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, decimal-points, precision-scale

How can I preserve an imported shapefile's original precision decimals in QGIS? Whenever I import an ESRI shapefile into QGIS, it automatically rounds off all fields containing decimals (data type float) into double real number, with 0 precision (only showing the whole number, integer digits, and nothing after the decimal point. I've tried formatting and otherwise changing data type. My only workaround/fix has been to create a new field within QGIS having the correct precision level and then copy the original field's contents into it. But there has to be a way to avoid this.
I am importing the shapefile into QGIS as a vector layer, through the add vector dataset window. I first manipulate the associated DBF file in Stata (import/export DBF file). The fields in question are calculated fields generated in Stata in format float. It doesn't look like the issue is merely one of display. The numbers are rounded to integers when looking through the attribute table, as well as when using the identify features tool. For example, One field in particular has an original possible value range between 0 and 1. Upon import into QGIS everything below 0.5 shows as 0, and everything over 0.5 shows as 1. There is nothing more there.

Comment: How are you importing it? If you're adding the shapefile as a layer it's a table display problem in QGIS the data values are unchanged but if you're changing type a description of that process would help.